# ¿Cómo adaptar una imagen de fondo con degradado?

Tags: html5, css3

Cómo adapto una imagen de fondo con degradado con una resolución de 150x150.

La imagen de fondo se divide en varias partes, como logro adaptar la imagen de degradado correctamente.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: url(http://dominointernet.s3.amazonaws.com/web/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/home-slider-bg-gris.png) center center fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>contenido, contenido</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí lo tienes en RGB, espero que te sirva!

```css
body {
background-color: rgb(238,238,238);
@include filter-gradient(#eeeeee, #cccccc, horizontal);
@include background-image(radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgb(238,238,238) 0%,rgb(204,204,204) 100%));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>contenido, contenido</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Grandioso el ejemplo :), pero viéndolo bien mejor quedaría el blanco más centrado o en el centro, ¿Cómo lo haría amigo?

Comment: He editado el código @May

Comment: esta todo perfecto amigo, el ejemplo con solo css, puedes incluirlo es de mucha ayuda, pero si en vez de ello fuera una imagen como la adaptaria correctamente.

Comment: Pienso que siempre es mejor css que imagen. La imagen la usaríamos en el caso de que el fondo que se quiere usar fuera un mosaico o tuviera un dibujo con el que hacer el background de la web. La respuesta de @FelipeMoctezuma también es buena con el uso de la imagen, considera darle un punto para arriba pues se ha tomado su tiempo para responderte y es buena respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba añadiendo

`html,body{
   height:100%;
}`

en tu archivo css y quitando `center center fixed` de la propiedad `background` en el body

```css
html,body{
   height:100%;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: url(http://inidesing.com/imagenes/grad.png) ;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>contenido, contenido</div>
</body>
</html>
```